# WP_Query () using taxonomy, custom post types

Tags: custom-field, query

I want to implement this query using `WP_Query()`.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM wp_posts as posts 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta as postmeta 
        ON (postmeta.post_ID = posts.ID) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships as taxonomy_rel 
        ON (taxonomy_rel.object_id = posts.ID) 
    WHERE posts.post_type='care-agency' 
        AND posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-listtype' 
        AND postmeta.meta_value = 'Enhanced Listing' 
    GROUP by posts.post_title 
    ORDER BY posts.post_title 
    ASC
```

Comment: What do you exactly want as the result?

Comment: Close voting as not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'care-agency', 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-listtype', 'meta_value' => 'Enhanced Listing' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        //Here goes my loopy stuff
    endwhile;
}
```

All taken from the codex on WP_Query.